# Intersections of Three Subgroups

Tags: group-theory

I encountered this elementary question which I didn't manage to prove or disprove successfully.
Let $G$ be some group and $K_1,K_2,K_3 \leq G$ s.t. 
$$G = <K_1,K_2,K_3>.$$
Furthermore, suppose that $\forall \sigma \in S_3$ it holds that $$K_{\sigma(1)} = <K_{\sigma(1)} \cap K_{\sigma(2)},K_{\sigma(1)} \cap K_{\sigma(3)}>,$$
i.e every subgroup is generated by its intersection with the two others.

Then for every three cosets $g_1K_1, g_2K_2, g_3K_3$, if every pair of cosets intersect then all three cosets intersect. That is, if $g_iK_i \cap g_jK_j \ne \emptyset$ for all possible $i,j$, then $g_1K_1 \cap g_2K_2 \cap g_3 K_3 \ne \emptyset$.

I managed to reduce the question to showing the statement on $g_1=g_2=e$ - this is just because if $g_1K_1,g_2K_2$ intersect then the intersection is coset of $K_1 \cap K_2$.

I also noticed that without the requirement that every subgroup is generated by the intersections, this statement is false - the counterexample is three (affine) lines in a plane that create a triangle. I don't see how to use the extra property though...